# Laravel - do not continue after form validator if ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to create a ajax form validation that verifies that form data and gives user instant feedback before really submitting the form.

For this i added a javascript function on form submit:

```
<form id="x" onsubmit="return dosubmit(this)" action="{{ url('/x') }}" method="POST">

<script>
    function dosubmit(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: $(form).serializeArray()
        }).done(function (data) {
            form.submit();
        }).fail(function (data) {
            alert('error');
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

And i have custom a form validator request:

```
class X extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

When my ajax request fails everything works fine. My form validator returns the error in json and i can display it to user. The problem is that when it is successful it actually posts the data two times - first time from the ajax request and second time because i call form.submit() after ajax request is successful. Because i want to redirect the user after submit i would actually like only the second submit to reach the controller. This means i have to stop the ajax request after validation. My current workaround is that i have a line like this in my controller:

```
public function store(X $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return;
    }

    // only actual request reaches here
}
```

This works, but its not pretty. I don't like including this line in my controller. I would be happy if i could do something similar in my request validator, but I cant find a good way to return after validation from there. Any ideas how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
<script>
    function dosubmit(form) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,    // make ajax not async
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: $(form).serializeArray()
        }).done(function (data) {
            form.submit();
        }).fail(function (data) {
            alert('error');
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and in controller just do it normally without this...

<strike>if ($request->ajax()) {</strike>
    <strike>return;</strike>
<strike>}</strike>

And please give feedback if it works...I am also interested.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question.

Comment: I have understood it like this: You want to submit the form only once and get redirected with flash message of success or with error messages if validation fails? Right?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with some changed in javascript code. I think you're confused about what `deferred.done()` method will do. In your code, you're submitting your form twice.

Let me break down your js script, the `done()` method is used to do further actions after submitting your form ([Please refer](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)).

In your code, the first `$.ajax` actually submits your form to backend (here, if there are any errors from backend you can handle them in `fail` section). If the form submits successfully without any errors, then in `done` section you can define functions or actions about what you want to do after a successful form submission.

Instead of defining what to do after a successful form submission, you are resubmitting the same form again. So remove that part from js code and also the workaround you've done in your backend.

```
function dosubmit(form) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        type: 'post',
        data: $(form).serializeArray()
    }).done(function (data) {
        // form.submit();
        // handle successful form submission
    }).fail(function (data) {
        alert('error');
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand what i am doing and it is intended. The first submit is just meant to validate the data and if everything is correct then i want to submit the form again without ajax and with page refresh. The question was that how can i stop the first request from actually submitting the data and only validate it.

Comment: @user1985273 If you want to validate on first submit, then you need to create a separate route that validates the form in the controller (Add that route in URL section of Ajax); And then submit the form. I think you don't want to use any client side validations, right?